# fix prompt under zsh Shell

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, zsh

I'm trying to fix my prompt which looks weird. How can I fix it?

This is what it looks like:

```
\[\033[0;34m\][\u@\h] \[\033[1;32m\]\w\[\033[1;31m\]$(__git_ps1) \[\e[0m\]$ 

\[\033[0;34m\][\u@\h] \[\033[1;32m\]\w\[\033[1;31m\]$(__git_ps1) \[\e[0m\]$
```

Comment: That prompt is intended for *`bash`*, not `zsh`.

Comment: Are you using oh my zsh with a theme that has characters that don't exist in your font pack?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the problem is when you say "looks weird"?

Comment: Thanks for  your help. My zshrc was sourcing the bashrc.